# Create case sensitive database with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

By default database created with SQL server is case insensitive. If I add 2 keys with the same name but different case the second insertion is rejected.

How can I change this behavior and make the database case sensitive?

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to change your database collation to Latin1_General_CS_AS

Here's how to do that using T-Sql:

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabase
   COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: #longRunning #youveBeenWarned.  Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitivity is subject to collation of the data.

By default databases created with SQL Server inherit the server collation. By default column in tables created in a database inherit the database collation. Between these options there are plenty of opportunities to choose a case sensitive collation for your data, either by choosing one when you create the database or by choosing one when you design the table.

Read [Using SQL Server Collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the collation of the database. HOWEVER, please read in depth about all the issues inherent in this before proceeding.